# How to parse XML using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, xml, parsing

I have to parse the below XML :

```
var xml = <gallery>
<image full="/images/gallery-resort/Sole_East_Lobby.jpg"/>
<image full="/images/gallery-resort/Cool_Crisp.jpg"/>
<image full="/images/gallery-resort/07_AK_Sole_Lobby2.jpg"/>
</gallery>
```

I want get the values of **full** attribute from the **image** tag. This structure is not proper but I need these image paths to show the images. I have tried below code for this but didn't worked:

```
xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
$xml = $( xmlDoc ); 
$($xml).each(function(){
var v = $(this).find("gallery");
});
```

Please, check it folks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example that would create an array of the url's would be:

```
  var imgs =  $xml.find('image').map(function(){
     return $(this).attr('full');
  }).get();
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/o2u8FU8JNzqKGABfyvqh?p=preview)**</kbd>

Or you could use `each` and add a new element for every iteration in the loop

```
$xml.find('image').each(function(){
    $('<img>',{src: $(this).attr('full')}).appendTo('body');   
});
```

Comment: @ charlietfl thanks for your comment. I am trying to read this array of image using the following code `var farr = JSON.stringify(imgs,null,' ');
      for (i = 0; i < farr.length; i++) {
      alert(farr[i]);
  }`
But its read character by character instead of reading the complete image path on index of imgs variable. I have used JSON.stringify(imgs,null,' ') to decode the JSON to array but didn't worked. You can see response here:  `http://dev.soleeast.com/parseXML2.php`
Please, advice.